# how to get count of child elements using selenium web-driver for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have searched at numerous places but I am not getting an answer

here is my html :

```
    <form id="search_form_homepage" >
    ...
<div class="search__autocomplete" style="display: block;">
    <div class="acp-wrap js-acp-wrap">
        <div class="acp" data-index="0"><span class="t-normal">elephant</span>cheap auto</div>
        <div class="acp" data-index="1"><span class="t-normal">elephant</span>asia</div>        
        ...
        ...
        <div class="acp" data-index="2"><span class="t-normal">elephant</span>africa</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
</form>
```

I simply need to get the count of the `<div>` present within the `div` with class `acp-wrap js-acp-wrap`

I can reach this point but am stuck beyond :

```
let xyz = driver.findElements(By.className(".acp-wrap js-acp-wrap>div"));
```

Comment: Did you try this? let xyz = driver.findElements(By.className("acp"));

Comment: thanks , but how do I get the count ? if I do a console log it shows as ```Promise { <pending> }```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `By.css` to get element by this: `.acp-wrap js-acp-wrap > div`. Also, your selector is not correct. When you select an element by class, you need to put a period before the class name: `.acp-wrap.js-acp-wrap > div` (remove the space between `acp-wrap` and `js-acp-wrap`, too).

Here is how you can get that element now:

```
let xyz = driver.findElements(By.css(".acp-wrap.js-acp-wrap > div"));
```

Now to get the count, you can get the `length` property of `xyz`. But since `driver.findElement` returns a promise, you need to use async-await. You can create a function:

```
async function getCount() {
  let xyz = await driver.findElements(By.css(".acp-wrap.js-acp-wrap > div"));
  const count = xyz.length;
  return count;
}
```

### EDIT

When you call the function:

```js
getCount().then(function(count) {
  // your stuff there
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot , however whenever I use ```By.cssSelector``` it fails  with ``` By.cssSelector is not a function``` , do I need to be importing  ```cssSelector``` ? and if so from where ? ( I am using node js and selenium-webdriver )

Comment: also if I change this to : ```let xyz = await driver.findElements(By.css(".acp-wrap.js-acp-wrap > div"));``` and then return ```xyz.length``` it is printing as ```Promise { <pending> }```

Comment: I edited the question. Changed `cssSelector` on `css` and showed how to do things with the returned count when you call `getCount`.